# How to view the precise time of running an SQL statement ？

Tags: mysql, sql

It's for mysql.
In mysql, the default shows in seconds.
I want the time unit to be accurated to milliseconds.

Comment: mysql does not have this feature.  PostgresSql does, [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision)

Answer (score 1):

Check the link http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/mysql-servers-built-in-profiling-support/

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tend to find it a better thing to do at the app level. A query can be slow for a multitude of reasons:

- Dismal SQL statement
- Network latency (send the SQL, bring back the result)
- Parsing the result (eg date/datetime in ruby)

If you log the complete query time as seen by the app, you spot more bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Query Profiler for MySQL queries](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html).