# How to insert a microsecond-precision datetime into mysql？

Tags: mysql

I have a string like this:

```
2011-11-11 11:11:11.111111
```

and I need to insert it in MySql, into a datetime column. But after I insert it, it becomes

```
2011-11-11 11:11:11
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: How do you know that it becomes `2011-11-11 11:11:11`? Where did you see it formatted like so? Also what datatype is the column you are storing this value into?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision

Answer (score 63, accepted):

MySql 5.6+ supports [fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in Time Values, while previous versions don't.

A standard `datetime` column will not hold microsecond values, while a `datetime(6)` will. You can test it in MySql 5.6:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  d1 datetime,
  d2 datetime(6)
);

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES
('2011-11-11 11:11:11.111111', '2011-11-11 11:11:11.111111');

SELECT MICROSECOND(d1) as m1, MICROSECOND(d2) as m2
FROM your_table;

m1 | m2
-----------
0  | 111111
```

If you are not using MySql 5.6+ I would suggest you to use two columns, one for the datetime part, and one for the microseconds:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  dt datetime,
  us int
);

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES
('2011-11-11 11:11:11.111111', MICROSECOND('2011-11-11 11:11:11.111111'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your correctting my question and your answer very much。My English is so poor。

Comment: Word to the wise: don't use ms to signify microseconds, as ms is the official sign for milliseconds.

Comment: The above SQL statements work for me but I can't Create Table or Alter Table with fractional seconds columns using Workbench GUI.

Comment: Can you find a reference that this is `5.6+`? I don't see it in the 5.6 release notes.

Comment: The 5.5 fractional time is a good source I suppose: "when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, it discards any fractional part and does not store it." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fractional-seconds.html

Answer (score 8):

use data type of datetime(**6**) or timestamp(**6**) in your table and insert current time with NOW(**6**) to get 6 digits of fractional seconds.

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [Fractional Seconds in Time Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> A trailing fractional seconds part is permissible for temporal values in contexts such as literal values, and in the arguments to or return values from some temporal functions. Example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT MICROSECOND('2010-12-10 14:12:09.019473');
> +-------------------------------------------+
> | MICROSECOND('2010-12-10 14:12:09.019473') |
> +-------------------------------------------+
> |                                     19473 |
> +-------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> However, when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, it discards any fractional part and does not store it.

Note that this behaviour [has changed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in v5.6.4.

Answer (score 3):

Some samples of inserting datetime values into MySQL(5.6.17)

```
create database if not exists mydb;
use mydb;
drop table if exists sample;
create table sample (c1 integer, c2 datetime(6),c3 varchar(30));
insert into sample values (1, '2014-07-25 11:18:10.999999', 'Actual Given Value');
insert into sample values (2, now(6), 'From NOW(6) function');
insert into sample values (3, now(), 'From NOW() function');
insert into sample values (4, sysdate(6), 'From sysdate(6) function');
insert into sample values (5, sysdate(), 'From sysdate() function');

select * from sample;

 # c1, c2, c3
'1', '2014-07-25 11:18:10.999999', 'Actual Given Value'
'2', '2014-07-25 11:27:27.314114', 'From NOW(6) function'
'3', '2014-07-25 11:27:27.000000', 'From NOW() function'
'4', '2014-07-25 11:27:27.429121', 'From sysdate(6) function'
'5', '2014-07-25 11:27:27.000000', 'From sysdate() function'
```

Comment: MySQL(5.6.17) does not support datetime(<fractional-seconds>). You need at least MySQL Version 5.6.4.