# Logging duration of store procedure in milliseconds in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to log the duration of a procedure in MILLISECONDS. 
The below statement worked in SQL Server fine.

```
 /* Log the duration of this procedure */
        @DurationMillisecs INT,
        @StartTime = GETDATE(),
        SET @DurationMillisecs = DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, GETDATE())
```

I am now trying to do this in MySQL, after some research i tried the below method but they are returning the same value as each other. So i am guessing UNIX_TIMESTAMP doesn't calculate in milliseconds.

```
SET StartTime =  UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
SET DurationMillisecs =  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - StartTime;
SELECT DurationMillisecs;
```

I have also tried below but the same problem.

```
SET StartTime =  now();
SET DurationMillisecs = DATEDIFF( StartTime, now());
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: thanks. Did TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,StartTime, now()); but cant find valid milliseconds way.

Comment: This page suggests that you should be able to:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Alternatively, if you are calling the sp from Coldfusion, .net, or something like that, they have tickcounts.

Comment: tried SET DurationMillisecs = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,StartTime, now());  still no luck.

Comment: I'm using java, and the requirement is that it has to be within the store procedure. thank for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out its actually because this was added as a feature in version 5.6.4.

Which can be found here [millisecond support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision%22millisecond%20bug%22)