# How to save time in milli-seconds in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, time

I am working on an API **(PHP)** which provides me time in `Minutes:Seconds:Milli-seconds format (01:21:91)`. I don't know how to save it in mysql. I also need to make some operations in that time. Please help me with this.

Comment: Dont know if this will help. But seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision

Comment: I think you can pass datetime to mysql built in method like this it will return you miliseconds. MICROSECOND('2010-12-10 14:12:09.019473');

Comment: please tell us which mysql version you are using, there is a pretty easy way for mysql 5.6 and higher

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.5

Comment: @lakumg then u will have to split it into to rows

Comment: @FelixLahmer how? I am not getting idea here. :(

Comment: @lakumg i gave you a working example, look my answer below, I will be away for like 30 mins now, if you need anything else, just comment EDIT: i meant columns before, not rows

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not working with mySQL 5.6 or higher you have to split it into two columns.
The one for the datetime (dttme)
and the other one for the microsecond (mcrscnds)

```
CREATE TABLE microseconds (
  dttme datetime,
  mcrscnds int
);

INSERT INTO microseconds VALUES
  ('2014-05-15 09:22:37.456789', MICROSECOND('2014-05-15 09:22:37.456789'));
```

Comment: So, not *rows* then? ;-)