# datetime doesn't save decisecond

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

So I read here : [Why doesn't MySQL support millisecond / microsecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision) that from the version 5.6.4, the datetime format should take until milliseconds.

But it doesn't work for me even for deciseconds it doesn't take. When I do my "INSERT" query, the value saved looks like this "2014-09-15 15:05:54".

The value I wanted to insert look like this : "2014-09-15T15:05:54.0"
So when I do comparaison, I get errors :/

Here is my INSERT Query :

```
            $bdd->query('INSERT INTO ev
            (id_event, ts, sp, lg, dir)
            VALUES 
            (NULL,"'.$evTs.'","'.$ev_sp.'","'.$ev_lg.'","'.$ev_dir.'")');
```

Where "$evTs" is the timestamp.

**Update 1**

How I create my table ev :

```
'CREATE TABLE `ev` (
`id_event` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ts` datetime NOT NULL,
`sp` int(32) NOT NULL,
`lg` int(32) NOT NULL,
`dir` int(32) NOT NULL,
`nbr_voie` int(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_event`)
```

)

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your `ev` table. You get this i.e. with `SHOW CREATE TABLE ev`. It's got to be DATETIME(3) to get milliseconds.

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1) A timestamp in PHP is an integer in whole seconds, so maybe you store the wrong value. 2. The result you get might be formatted in a way that hides milliseconds. It would help if you could show the final query. These variables are not very helpful.

Comment: You've got to use `ALTER COLUMN` to get [fractional second support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), as I said. Then use the syntax as mentioned by @MarcB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `T` is not part of a valid mysql timestring. MySQL's date/time string format has always been

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

and now that fractional seconds are supported

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sssss
```

Nowhere in that format is there ANY support for `T`. You'll have to use a `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse your "non-standard" format into something MySQL will accept. Or even simply just use a string replacement and do `REPLACE('yourstring', 'T', ' ')`

Comment: Yes, I noticed the "T" too but when I did the "INSERT" I had it in the correct format till the seconds. Ok, I will try your answer tomorrow. Thanks.