# I want to calculate time which is taken by SQL query in MySQL for execution

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I'm new in MySQL so is there any way to calculate the time taken by SQL query in execution inside MySQL workbench or using a terminal.
I want to learn optimization of SQL query so that's why I want to calculate the time taken by SQL query.

Comment: my bad, to fast :(

Comment: yes in MySQL-WORKBENCH or using terminal.

Comment: perhaps this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39860634) I added over in that dupe target is useful